# How to insert a dictionary into dataframe's row based on grouped values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have this data:

```
                                 count
Year         Month  Code    
2016         1      ENE001SOLC   121
                    SAL016DECL   92
                    TRN002SIGN   54
                    HAB002SOLC   38
                    TRE001SIGN   37
                    ESP003SOLC   36
                    TRN002SOLC   32
             2      ENE001SOLC   151
                    CAT001SOLC   143
                    VIT001SOLC   90
                    TRE001SIGN   80
                    TRN002SOLC   74
                    BOM001SOLC   72
             3      ENE001SOLC   114
                    ENT002JUST   96
                    TRE001SIGN   94
                    TRN002SIGN   89
                    ENT002APOR   76
                    TRN002SOLC   56
```

This data samole is grouped by year and month. It displays the frequencies of a given code as you can see.

What i want to do, is to take all the code values that appears in the same month, and put them into a python a dictionary where the key is the code, and the count is the value so i can have in the same row, all the keys and their respective counts. The desired ouput should look like this:

```
Year         Month  Code_count    
2016         1      {ENE001SOLC: 121, SAL016DECL: 92, TRN002SIGN: 54, HAB002SOLC: 38, HAB002SOLC: 38, TRE001SIGN: 37, ESP003SOLC: 36, TRN002SOLC: 32}

             2      {ENE001SOLC: 151, CAT001SOLC: 143, VIT001SOLC: 90, TRE001SIGN: 80, TRN002SOLC: 74, BOM001SOLC: 72}
```

You can see what my idea is. I have tried to use the `pd.to_dict()` method but with this i get all the code values with their code but the grouping is not respected. How could i do this ?? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following,

```
result = (df.reset_index()
            .groupby(['Year','Month'])
            .apply(lambda x:x.set_index('Code')['count'].to_dict())
         )
```

Comment: `groupby(['Year','Month'])`  will split the data into unique year month combination and `apply` conducts operation for each group, in this case, `to_dict`